# Cannot find models after restarting Nextjs API project, MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Model"

Tags: mongoose, next.js

I have a Nextjs project with a Nextjs API with Mongoose, everything works fine since I stop the project (I am in development mode) and restart it, here is how I instantiate the Model:

`const Category = mongoose.models.Category || mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema); export default Category;`

I have to do `mongoose.models.Category ||` because it seems like the model is recreated on every api call so I have to check if it have been already created. This works fine but I suspect that have something to do with my actual problem: `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Model".` that is given to me after I restart the project, this happens on every model I have.

Here is an example of how I am using my API routes for another model, the Scan model, I think that it is exploding on the populate because if I remove it here on the Scan model it works:

```
        /** ANCHOR
         * * Pick the latest 10 scans (can be used also to sort by any value and limit the scans)
         */
        if (sort && limit) {
          scans = await Scan.find()
            .sort({ [`${sort}`]: -1 })
            .limit(+limit)
            .populate(["category", "zone"]);
        }

        /** ANCHOR
         * * Pick the scans that are untouched
         */
        if (untouched && limit) {
          scans = await Scan.find({
            measurements: {
              $elemMatch: {
                measurement: null,
              },
            },
          })
            .limit(+limit)
            .populate(["category", "zone"]);
        } else if (untouched) {
          scans = await Scan.find({
            measurements: {
              $elemMatch: {
                measurement: null,
              },
            },
          }).populate(["category", "zone"]);
        }
```

When I restart the project I have to delete my MongoDB database and after that it works fine, but I loose all the data.

I would like to check if the model have been created because otherwise nextjs recreate the model on every API call but also to prevent deleting the database every time I restart the project.